# How to prevent geom_area to order alphabetically in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m using `geom_area` to plot a 100% plot. The problem I´m having is that it is sorting the data alphabetically for the plot which I don´t want. This is an example of the data I´m using:

```
t var val
0   A  28
0   B  47
0   C  50
0   D  20
1   A  19
1   B  21
```

and this is the plot i´m getting: 
[image]

the thing is I want to customize the order by which the data is ploted. For example, I want D to be in the top of the graph, B to be below D and then A and C but I cant figure out how to do it.

This is the code needed to create this graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(t=rep(0:23,each=4),var=rep(LETTERS[1:4],4),val=round(runif(4*24,0,50)))   
ggplot(d, aes(x=t,y=val,group=var,fill=var)) + geom_area(position="fill")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a new factor variable with the desired order, and then use it for the `fill` aesthetic, like this:

```
fill.order <- factor(d$var, levels = c('D', 'A', 'C', 'B'))
ggplot(d, aes(x=t,y=val)) +
  geom_area(position="fill", aes(x=t, y=val, fill=fill.order)) +
  labs(fill = 'var')
```

[image]

Comment: That´s just what i needed. Thanks